# How to connect java and Adf.ly?

Tags: java

Is there any way in java to make code: Example if someone clicks on skipAd on adf.ly link Int will increase. Example 2: I click the button, it will take me to a adfly link. and when i click skipAd on adf.ly: in the app int will increase for 1(int++).
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

First of: StackOverflow hates it when people come here showing that they have taken **zero** effort to find a solution for the problem.

Secondly:

Your question is very unspecific.

Are you and your friend on the same network? If so, you might want to consider using *ARP-Poisoning* in order to inject custom *JavaScript* into the webpage that will function as an `EventListener`. Obviously this will only work if he is visiting AdFly via an *HTTP* connection and since Adfly-Links are generated with an *HTTPS prefix*, you will rarely find people using *HTTP* (despite the fact that they still don't enforce *HTTPS*, grumpf).

There are probably tons of other solutions but they will all involve tinkering with his/your webtraffic. And no offense, but I feel like you should probably learn some more Java before taking on such a big task.

Answer (score 0):

More than in 'java' it would be easier to do it in 'JavaScript'. You'll have to monitor the `onClick` event of  that `SkipAd` button and then you can increase your counter.
I advise you to make your question even more clearer in *why-you-have-to-do-it* department to avoid down votes

Comment: Damn you and your quick typing skills.